# how to make UIBarButton Right Justified in IPhone

Tags: iphone

I have added the `Toolbar` dynamically and in that i added `barbutton` dynamically but it appears on left side I want it to appear on the Right Side.
Can AnyOne help me Out with this My code Goes Like this

```
 CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 205, 320, 40);
 UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
 toolbar.barStyle =UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
 toolbar.tintColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];


 UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle: @"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(foo)];
 NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:backButton,nil];

 [toolbar setItems:array];
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the Answer by Simply adding the following Line

UIBarButtonItem *BtnSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];

and adding this in array
Now the Code Look Like this

self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 480) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 205, 320, 40);
    UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
    toolbar.barStyle =UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
    toolbar.tintColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

```
UIBarButtonItem *BtnSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle: @"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(foo)];
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:BtnSpace,backButton,nil];

[toolbar setItems:array];
```